# Can the creator of all the encrytion algorithm hack our accounts?

Tags: security, hash, md5

If let's say for example the creator of MD5. He created the MD5. So can he hack our accounts or other sites that are using this algorithm?

And not just MD5, other encryption algorithms too. How is it possible that it says it is almost impossible to hack those that are using these algorithms, they are design by human too.

Please explain

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and http://crypto.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only advantage the inventor has, is a good understanding of the algorithm. He *can* try to insert a backdoor or a weakness, but well known algorithms are analyzed by many independend cryptographers, and hopefully they would discover such weaknesses (intended or not).

As long as you do not have a thorough understanding of the matter yourself, you will always have to trust in other people. So the longer an algorithm withstood crypto analysis, the more likely it is that you can trust it.

Comment: But how did he decided that say for example letter 'B' has this hash value(this is random): ers2234fgsbdsf09ji ? Is this complete random that the creator cannot pre-determine it?

Comment: @user2881063 - A hash algorithm is just like a math formula, you know exactly what the result will be for each start value. In fact this is what an attacker does with rainbow-tables, he precalculates all possible start values so he can later compare the resulting hashes. To mitigate this, one should use random salts and a slow hash function (MD5 is ways too fast so it should not be used to hash passwords). The randomness cannot come from the algorithm. If you are interested you may have a look at my tutorial about [safely storing passwords](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php).

Answer (score 1):

The creators of cryptosystems should not be able to easily break them, because the security of a soundly designed cryptosystem should only depend on the secrecy of the keys. This is known as [Kerckhoff's Prinicple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27_principle).